# How do I reset to the beginning of the code after it runs?

Tags: python

After the code runs all the way for the first time, I want it to be able to go back to the first input and allow the user to input another word.

Do I need to create a `for` or `while` loop around the program?

```
import re    
import requests

search = input('What word are you looking for?: ')
first = re.compile(search)

source = input ('Enter a web page: ')
r = requests.get(source)
ar = r.text

mo = first.findall(ar)
print (mo)

print('Frequency:', len(mo))
```

Comment: _Do I need to create a for or while loop?_ Yes, any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a loop is needed:

```
import re    
import requests

while True:
    search = input('What word are you looking for?: ')
    # per comment, adding a conditional stop point.
    if search == "stop":
        break

    first = re.compile(search)

    source = input ('Enter a web page: ')
    r = requests.get(source)
    ar = r.text

    mo = first.findall(ar)
    print (mo)

    print('Frequency:', len(mo))
```

Comment: This is an infinite loop, may be you should add a condition to break from the loop.

Comment: Done, added the break.,

Comment: It would also be good to move the operations to a function, and then just call that function inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yep a while look is the way to go.

Make sure you don't have an infinite loop though. (You want some way to `break` out...

I would recommend just adding this to the `search`, so if they type `exit` it breaks out of the look. I have also added .lower() so Exit, EXIT, etc also work.

```
import re    
import requests

while True:
    search = input('What word are you looking for?: ')

    if search.lower() == "exit": #break out of the loop if they type 'exit'
        break

    first = re.compile(search)

    source = input ('Enter a web page: ')
    r = requests.get(source)
    ar = r.text

    mo = first.findall(ar)
    print (mo)

    print('Frequency:', len(mo))
```

Comment: This is just a copy of the [other, earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58704544/2745495)

Comment: Well there wasn't another answer when I submitted it... They weren't far apart so that's probably why. (When I clicked on the question it was only 20 minutes old)